# Using different cloud hosts for app and db/will there be latency with Mongo Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, web, cloud, paas

Is it ok to host both a web app and db server on different cloud providers?  Traditionally you really needed to host both on the same network - but I'm wondering if, with modern networks, this is less of a necessity.

I have a web app (Aurelia/ASP.Net Core) hosted on Linode and I need to add a mongo db server.  I really don't want to have to manage the db servers - so would prefer to use a cloud service like MongoAtlas or mLab etc but my concern is latency.   I'm hoping that I could use either of these if I chose a data center in the same country/location as my Linodes are hosted.

My app should be ok with not-so-real-time responses - but lags of a few seconds won't work.

Can anyone comment on experiences with this?

Comment: This probably would actually be better suited to [serverfault.com](https//serverfault.com) than here, since it is basically asking about networking between hosts. I could also comment that is somewhat a broad question and would actually be completely subjective to your own host configuration and the providers used.

Comment: On a productive note, I would suggest you "look deeply" into such providers and see where there actual implementations are. For instance it would not surprise to find out that three different service providers "actually" host your services within the same data center ( such as an AWS provision ) if you actually looked at all the specific details. So maybe you should invest some of your time into looking at exactly that. Or indeed what combination of providers would end up which such a real result.

Comment: If you are concerned about the effect of network latency on your application, the best approach would be to set up a small hosted DB deployment and test this out. MongoDB Atlas is available across AWS, Azure, and Google Cloud Platform regions (see: [Atlas FAQ for current regions](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/faq#where-available)), so you should be able to find a region close to your cloud hosting. You could also look at minimising network usage in your application code (eg. using projections to limit data returned by queries and `$set` to only update field values that have changed).